# Define global symbol (Error)

Tags: perl, package, global, explicit

I went through a couple of discussions to find the solution but none of them seem to be working in my case.

I have the following piece of code

```
print ("Choose from the following\n");
print ("op1 op2\n");

my $x = <>;  
chomp($x);     
print ("x is $x");

if ($x eq "op1")
{
my $DirA = "./A";
my $DirB = "./B"; # **I want to use this dirA and dir B below (Tried switch stmts but I 
#**get the same error)**
}

opendir my($dh), "$DirA" or die "Couldn't open dir DirA!";
my @files = readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;
system("rm -rf diffs");
system ("mkdir diffs\n");
foreach my $input (@list) {
.
.
.
}
```

I get this error: **Global symbol "$DirA" requires explicit package name at test_switch.tc**

Can someone please help me with the same. My intension is to add options/switches to my script.. Like "test.pl -A", "test.pl -B" for which I started with a case stmt. Please provide inputs on this.

Comment: Can you use perl modules?  If so, I suggest you consider using [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/~jv/Getopt-Long-2.39/lib/Getopt/Long.pm).  It will make your life a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$DirA` and `$DirB` are not global, they are only defined in the scope of the `if` statement in which they're declared with a `my`. In general, from [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html): "A `my` declares the listed variables to be local (lexically) to the enclosing block, file, or `eval`." To use them in any code that follows, you'll have to do something like:

```
my $DirA;
my $DirB;

if ($x eq "op1") {
  $DirA = "./A";
  $DirB = "./B";
} else {
  $DirA = ...
  $DirB = ...
}
```

Note the `else`: you should also do something if `$x` is *not* `"op1"` because as it stands even if the code had run you'd have gotten an error when trying to pass an undefined value to `opendir`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am getting this error after adding that                                                                if ($x eq "op1"){
my $DirA = "./A";
my $DirB = "./B";
}
else{
my $DirA = "./C";
my $DirB = "./D";
}

opendir my($dh), "$DirA" or die "Couldn't open dir DirA!";                Use of uninitialized value in string at test_switch.tc line 47, <> line 1.
Couldn't open dir DirA! at test_switch.tc line 47, <> line . This is the opendir line

Comment: Don't put `my` inside the `if` and `else`. This will mask the variables with the same name defined outside the block. To make sure things are ok, `print "DirA = $DirA and DirB = $DirB\n"` before the `opendir`.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the variables *before* the `if` block and they will be accessible thereafter.

```
my $DirA;
my $DirB;

if ($x eq "op1") {
    $DirA = "./A";
    $DirB = "./B";
}
```